# Customer redeems an offer, vendor does what?

Tags: terminology

In a product I am working on, a customer can "accept" an offer.

They can then go to the vendor and redeem the offer.

The vendor-side interface has a button that will pop open the camera on iPad and scan the offer, the trouble is that I do not know what phrase to use as the button text.

1. "ACCEPT OFFER" is my first choice, but we are using accept in another context that would be hard to change.
2. "SCAN OFFER" is not bad, but that is not really the ultimate action the vendor is taking. This goes along the lines of using "Complete Application" rather than a button that says "Submit" for a form that completes and application.
3. Verify, authenticate etc have too much of a security driven connotation that does not really fit with this.
4. "Confirm Offer" is alright.

Any ideas for other words or phrases?

Comment: something that just came to mind is "Scan and Confirm Offer". Don't love it, but add it to the list of possibilities.

Comment: The vendor redeems the offer not the customer. Redeem is equivalent to sell, not to purchase.

Comment: @JamesRyan I thought so to some extent, however I saw these 3 examples from Webster that made me reconsider:

You can redeem this coupon at any store.
You have 90 days to redeem your winning lottery ticket.
This voucher can be redeemed for a free meal at several local restaurants.

Comment: How about validate offer?

Comment: Facilitating offer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "validate offer", which falls somewhere between emphasizing the authentication and the honoring aspects of the transaction, while simultaneously evoking both.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'Redeem Offer'

This might seem a bit strange because you would think of redeeming as what you do when you actually go to the vendor. 
However, if they are going to that effort, then they're pretty much dedicating themself to the whole process of redeeming the offer already.
Also, in the world of (free) offers, people are most accustomed to redeeming vouchers and scanned offers etc, so keep the language consistent with what's going through their heads.